# add multiple columns to an xts object

Tags: r, xts

I struggled a bit with how to do this concisely. My solution, using matrix(...) works but seems a bit sledge hammer like. Is there a better one?

I have an existing 1-row xts object (D1) and a non-xts vector (E1) that comes from an external source which I want to merge together:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("SPY")
data = get("SPY")
is.xts(data)

# Extract a single row xts object
D1 = data[1,]
index(D1)
# Get the numerical part as a vector
D1v = as.vector(D1)

# New data from external source to be merged
E1 = c(5,6,7,8,9,10)

# Combine into new vector
G1 = c(D1v, E1)
G1

# This fails, I think because xts treats G1 
# like a 1-column object, not a 1-row object?
testXts1 = xts(G1, order.by = index(D1))

testXts2 = xts(matrix(G1, nrow=1), order.by = index(D1))
index(testXts2)
testXts2
```

My question here is whether the matrix(G1, nrow=1) construct is the intended way to do this sort of thing, the issue being that xts requires X and index(X) to have the same dimensions.

Thanks!

Comment: You can save a little typing: `xts(t(G1), index(D1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what you want to do is relatively unusual (having a single row xts is unusual), I think the idiom you have found might be as good as anything else.

The other way I can think of would be to add each column one at a time:

```
D1$a = 5
D1$b = 6
D1$c = 7
D1$d = 8
D1$e = 9
```

This gives:

```
> D1
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted a b c d e
2007-01-03   142.25   142.86  140.57    141.37   94807600       122.03 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using names is a solution I found in other questions of this type but it seems better suited to adding just 1 or 2 new columns. In my case where I may receive 50 or a 100 it's too much typing. (For me!) I suspect it is an uncommon sort of thing I'm doing here. I receive a bit of data at odd times but want to keep it in some sort of a larger xts context. Thanks!

Comment: I tried some loop ideas, but they end up much more verbose than your matrix approach.